# XAMPP Mac Virtual Host Configuration

Tags: macos, apache-http-server, xampp, virtual-host

I am not sure what I am missing but after updating my httpd.conf file by `uncommenting the string to allow httpd-vhost.conf`
to allow httpd-vhost.conf and update httpd-vhost.conf

update https-vhost.conf file:

```
# localhost
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName localhost
    DocumentRoot "/Applications/XAMPP/htdocs"
    <Directory "/Applications/XAMPP/htdocs">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes execCGI
        AllowOverride All
        Order Allow,Deny
        Allow From All
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

# My custom host
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName mysite.dev
    DocumentRoot "/Users/myusername/Projects/myNewsite"
    <Directory "/Users/myusername/Projects/myNewsite">
        Options All
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
    ErrorLog "logs/mysite.local-error_log"
</VirtualHost>
```

and add a new vhost with a new server name.

Last I updated my OX host file with

```
127.0.0.1  mysite.dev
```

But when I type `http://mysite.dev` into the browser the default XAMPP page is displayed.

I also updated the httpd.conf file and changed

```
User myusername
Group nogroup
```

Does anyone see anything I missed and why I can not get my site up?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I had a few characters in the vhost file that were throwing and error. That is why my host name was not working.